java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal key values seen in w3c capabilities
I am trying to prepare a test automation on my mobile phone.
For that I did necessary preparation like:

Appium Server installed and running
Verifying the UDID via adb devices in cmd

After setting the capabilities, I am facing the error that the mobile phone cannot be reached.
Within Eclipse, I receive the following error message:
I replaced the UID with XXX (but for the UID I used the name given by "adb devices". Moreover, I replaced the Host information and the ip with YYY.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal key values seen in w3c capabilities: [addActivity, addPackage, deviceName, platformVersion, udid]
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.


Host info: host: 'YYY', ip: 'YYY.YYY.YYY.YY'


Build info: version: '4.23.1', revision: '656257d8e9'


System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8'


Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver


Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {addActivity: com.sec.android.app.popupca..., addPackage: com.sec.android.app.popupca..., deviceName: Galaxy A40, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 11, udid: XXX}]}]


Capabilities {addActivity: com.sec.android.app.popupca..., addPackage: com.sec.android.app.popupca..., deviceName: Galaxy A40, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 11, udid: XXX}


org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

I executed the following code.
My target was opening the calculator app on the mobile phone with that script.
Instead of that behaviour I received the error messages shown above.
Therefore, my question is:
What could be the reason for that issue?
Can an error be detected in my code?
Is there an additional topic I need to consider and double check for the setup?
I appreciate any kind of help and ideas.
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;


public class AppiumTest1 {

    static AppiumDriver driver;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
        firstProgram();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            System.out.println(exp.getCause());
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
        public static void firstProgram() throws Exception
        {
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy A40");
            cap.setCapability("udid", "XXX");
            cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "11");
            
            cap.setCapability("addPackage", "com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator");
            cap.setCapability("addActivity", "com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.Calculator");
            
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

            driver = new AppiumDriver(url, cap);
            
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
}


Try this,
With Appium 1.x, the server would accept commands by default on http://localhost:4723/wd/hub. The /wd/hub base path was a legacy convention from the days of migrating from Selenium 1 to Selenium 2, and is no longer relevant.

So Use,
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/");

In place of
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");


If you want to retain the old behaviour, you can set the base path via a command line argument as follows:
appium --base-path=/wd/hub


Docs Link : Appium 2.x
